# Binning a pandas dataframe using datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is an extract from my dataframe with shape (7800, 3)

```
             datetime   ui1 ui2
0 2019-01-01 00:12:45  0.20   4
1 2019-01-01 01:04:17  0.12  36
2 2019-01-01 04:27:01  0.63   7
3 2019-01-01 06:31:09  0.31  40
4 2019-01-01 07:43:28  0.48   9
```

I want to bin the dataframe into bins using the datetime column with interval of 3H to look like this

```
             datetime  ui1 ui2  ui1a ui2a
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00  nan nan   nan  nan
1 2019-01-01 00:03:00 0.20   4  0.12   36
2 2019-01-01 00:06:00 0.63   7   nan  nan
3 2019-01-01 00:09:00 0.31  40  0.48    9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend save the group bin into `list`

```
out = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime',freq='3H')).agg(list)
Out[386]: 
                              ui1      ui2
datetime                                  
2019-01-01 00:00:00   [0.2, 0.12]  [4, 36]
2019-01-01 03:00:00        [0.63]      [7]
2019-01-01 06:00:00  [0.31, 0.48]  [40, 9]
```